# Undefined index error in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am running an Ajax tutorial example and a line gives error in controller file. What I'm doing is if a field is blank and user blurs out of it an error will display below the field.

Here is the whole function in MessagesController.php

```
public function validate_form()
    {
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
        {
            $this->request->data['Message'][$this->request->params['form']['field']] = $this->request->params['form']['value'];
            $this->Message->set($this->request->data);
            if($this->Message->validates())
            {
                $this->autoRender = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                $error = $this->validateErrors($this->Message);
                $this->set('error', $error[$this->request->params['form']['field']]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The error line is this:

```
$this->request->data['Message'][$this->request->params['form']['field']] = $this->request->params['form']['value'];
```

And error is this

```
Undefined index: form [APP\Controller\MessagesController.php, line 30]
```

Actually the tutorial was based on previous version of Cake but I have made proper changes compatible with current version but still error shows. Can someone please tell me what might be wrong in this line or elsewhere in the code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `var_dump($this->request->params);` & check if form really exists in it or not.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->request->params` does not contain a `form` index.

I think you should be looking at your `$this->request->data`?

`$this->request->params` has only information about your request: the action, the controller, any named parameters and so on.

The error you get is actually normal.

Add comment with link to tutorial.

Comment: It is video tutorail on YT. This guy is very knowledgable and I have been following his tutorials for sometime now. He explains two tutorials on using Ajax. First one is running fine but second one not while the whole code is same except for some changes I made to make it compatible with latest version of Cakephp. Here is link (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ71psonQx0)

Comment: Hi, I had a quick look and in CakePHP 2.4 you need to use $this->request->data, not the params. So have you tried my suggested answers? replace `$this->request->params['form']['field']` with `$this->request->data['field'];` (no 'form') and replace `$this->request->params['form']['value']` with `$this->request->data['value'];` (again no 'form' index).